# vba filtering multiple sheets based on the same criteria

Tags: vba, excel

hopefully an easy question but not for a newbie like me... I have a workbook with master data and ca. 15 sheets, sheets 3-11 have data in the same format, which I want to filter by the same number, then delete other data and save. My (very amateurish) attempt was:

```
Sub Filterdata()
'Tab 3 - Vehicle info - filter by column A
Sheets("Vehicle Info").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>1", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
     'delete blanks
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Range("A2").Select
'
'Tab 4 - Gifts - filter by column A
Sheets("Gifts to third parties (£50+)").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>1", _
Operator:=xlAnd
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$50000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
     'delete blanks
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$50000").AutoFilter Field:=1
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
Range("A2").Select
```

there were 10 more paragraphs like that, each relating to another worksheet within the same workbook - all need to be filtered in the same column (A) using the same number (1, in this case). 
Could I replace this massive code with something shorter? (the first two worksheets also need to be filtered but by column B but because there is only two paragraphs, I can live with that), thank you.

Thank you for your help, the code seems to work perfectly on the first tab but then continues for a long time and when interrupted, " .Rows(x).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp"  code is highlighed. Please find attached a screenshot showing the structure of the document, the two sheets in red have the company number in column B, other sheets have the company number in column A.
Some sheets may not have any data for e.g. company 3, then I'd need to delete all other irrelevant data (for other companies) and leave the tab blank[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3bK3.jpg)

Comment: So you delete the row of any blanks in Column A, but first you make any cells that are not 1 blank, so in effect you are deleting everything that is not blank and is not 1 for Column A:A on every sheet? Looks like you want to pass in the "`1`" to the method so that you can change this in the future...

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the sample data?

Comment: Hi Glitch_Doctor, thank you for your comment - you are right, I was hoping to have a code with 1 as an example of company number used to filter the master data file, so that I could change 1 to a different company number in the future. Effectively, I need to create 500+ files for different companies from one master file e.g. a file for company 1, company 2 etc. (some numbers are not assigned to any company though and some data sets have no data for e.g. company 5 but has data for company 7 etc.) Sorry, if it was unclear

Comment: @Dan - So to be clear, you are going through each sheet and deleting all companies that are not company 1, saving it as "company 1 file", then going back and doing the same thing for comapnies 2, 3, 4, etc.  So the next question would be, how many companies are there?

Comment: @A Cohen, that's right, there are about 500 companies but because we generate those files in batches, we do 40-50 in one go. To make the code more dynamic and more user-friendly, I created an Excel document where they would paste the company numbers they want to use for filtering/saving in a specified row of cells (say 1-50, some numbers missing), then concatenate function combines those numbers with the code and gives the user the code to be copied into VBA - it now works but the code is long (though quick) so I split it into subs within the code - they can copy the entire code in one go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work slightly better than the previous version.  Let me know if you have any other issues

```
    Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ShNum As Integer
    Dim rwCcnt As Long
    Dim num As Long

    Dim x As Long

    For num = 1 To 25   '---Number of companies to loop
        For ShNum = 3 To 11   '---Sheets to loop
            Set ws = Worksheets(ShNum)
            rwCnt = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With ws
                For x = rwCnt To 2 Step -1   '---Rows to loop
                    If .Cells(x, 1).Value2 <> num Or .Cells(x, 1).Value2 = "" Then
                        If x = 2 And .Cells(x, 1).Value2 = "" Then Exit For
                        .Rows(x).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
                    End If
                Next x
            End With
        Next ShNum
    Next num

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help with it! I've added more information into the my (edited) question

Comment: @A Cohen, it seemed to do the trick when tested, thank you! I'll add it into my procedure, unfortunately got sidetracked with another challenge at work...